# How to store pointers (or references) to objects in a std::set

Tags: c++, stl

Are there any proper means in the C++11 STL to store object pointers in a `std::set`, and have them sorted properly by the object's `operator <` method?

There is, of course, the possibility of writing my own `Compare` type and passing that to the `set` as its second template argument, but I'd imagine that the STL would provide a much more convenient way.

A bit of googling revealed `std::reference_wrapper`, which in my opinion should allow code like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <set>

struct T {
    int val;
    bool operator <(T& other) {
        return (this->val < other.val);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<std::reference_wrapper<T>> s;
    T a{5};
    s.insert(a);
}
```

But in fact, this causes a compiler error:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test.cpp -o test
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/functional:49:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::reference_wrapper<T>'
      and 'const std::reference_wrapper<T>')
      { return __x < __y; }
               ~~~ ^ ~~~
```

(the gcc error is similar, but a lot longer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your less-than operator a non-member, and give it `const` reference parameters:

```
struct T {
    int val;
};

bool operator <(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return (lhs.val < rhs.val);
}
```

This allows for implicit conversions on from `std::reference_wrapper<T>` to `T` on both LHS and RHS of the `<` operator, whereas the member version only allows for an implicit conversion on the RHS. Symmetry between LHS and RHS of binary operators is one of the classic arguments for implementing them as non-members.

Comment: Sorry, but the compiler error appears to stay the same

Comment: @mic_e have you tried the non-member? That works fine on G++.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I still don't fully understand how or why that fixes things, but I've confirmed it does with clang

Comment: @MooingDuck I assume there needs to be an implicit conversion from reference_wrapper to T on both sides of the `<`, but the member only allows it on the RHS.

Comment: @mic_e I added an explanation.

Comment: @MooingDuck How does it have access? As far as I can see, there is only `operator T& () const;`

Comment: Actually this is a wrong approach, we should create custom std::less for your struct.
Check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394169/7918560

Answer (score 2):

The object a method is called on cannot be implicitly converted, so you need to implement comparison as a free function to use the conversion from reference_wrapper<T> to T.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to create a specialized `std::less` for our MyStruct.

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct  less<MyStruct>
    {
        bool operator() (const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs.a < rhs.a;
        }
    };

}
```

Remember `std::set` uses `std::less` by default to compare two elements.

Defined in header `<set>`

```
template<

    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it is "the right approach"?

Comment: Because ultimately implementation uses std::less to compare two elements and if it is not defined then it uses `<` operator. The other solution which is "to overload the `<` operator in our Class only to support use of our class as a key to map or as a memembr in set is wrong.
Defined in header <set>
  
template<

    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;